# Any checks for possible nefarious use?

Tags: discussion, scope

Not that I'm suggesting censorship, but are there any checks in the Physics Stack Exchange system that exclude questions seeking answers that might be used for *evil* or *destructive* purposes?

I suppose people capable of answering such questions (and of sounder mind) would flag or else avoid answering and thus prevent or at least limit the outcome.

Comment: See [this meta.SE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3528/263383) and its linked questions for prior discussion without specific reference to physics.SE.

Comment: I am not glossing over the potential seriousness of your question, but I do think the ship has already sailed on this point. For example, almost every type of  gun related question has been asked and many of them answered.  Other potential **physics** based large scale menances probably require lots of  money and high tech equipment, PSE can't stop any person or organisation with that level of resources and there are plenty of other sites that provide similar information. I do think Chemistry SE or Biology SE  may have to be more careful than here though.

Comment: He who gives up freedom for safety deserves neither. (C) Benjamin Franklin's Autobiographical Writings

Comment: We do get dangerous subversives on the site, but luckily supporters of Bohmian mechanics are easily spotted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is our stance on questions about legally or ethically questionable activities?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/996/)

Comment: @JohnRennie in light of your comment above, you are best placed to deal with this obvious threat to civilization as we know it today http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304931/can-mass-be-seen-as-a-hidden-variable-when-it-is-in-superposition

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how would be it a real problem, any feasible nefarious physics knowledge would require also a lot of [engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com) or [diy](https://diy.stackexchange.com) effort, which is offtopic here.

I think, we can simply ignore the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We deal in physics here. Anyone with legitimately nefarious motives that present a danger to people would likely be smart enough to ask their question in a way that doesn't reveal their intents. But more than that, we aren't the only source of physics out there. If someone comes by and wants to know the physics of something that seems like it could be used to hurt people, we are still going to answer the question. Information is not evil. Now, we aren't going to instruct them on how to build a thermonuclear device in their tool shed. That would be off-topic as an engineering question. And it would probably be more suitable on DIY.SE.

Physics isn't confidential and we don't keep secrets about it. The only thing holding back information could do is keep someone from realizing the safety hazards associated with an action, which might put more people at risk. Anyone actively looking to harm others isn't going to be able to do it with math equations alone (except Math Man, but he only does it in self-defense. Best superhero ever!) and we don't accept questions asking engineering or diy details.